# C# deserialize Json based on condition

Tags: c#, json

```
{
    "timeAgo": "6 minutes ago",
    "time": "07/11/2016 07:00 AM",
    "alertId": 145928,
    "details": {


    },
    "priority": 10,
    "type": 2,
    "isClosed": 0,
    "notesCount": 0,
    "patientAccountId": 680,
    "isRead": 0
  }
```

I want to deserialize the json based on the int value 'type', in such as way, I want the details to be different types

```
public class Notification
{
    public string timeAgo { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public int alertId { get; set; }
    public object details { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int isClosed { get; set; }
    public int notesCount { get; set; }
    public int patientAccountId { get; set; }
    public int isRead { get; set; }
}
```

if type = 1, then the object 'details' is of type A, if type = 2, 'details' is of type B and so on. There are about 25 values for type.

So, later I can do something like:

```
Notification n = ....
if (type == 1)
{
    A a = (a) n.details;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your json does not have appropriate typing included in the JSON, this will work.

This may need tweaking if your actual structure is more complex, but I managed to get this to work on your sample.

```
var instance = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Notification>(
    js,
    new ItemConverter());

public class ItemA : Item { }
public class ItemB : Item { }
public class Item { }

public class Notification
{
    public string timeAgo { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public int alertId { get; set; }
    public Item details { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int isClosed { get; set; }
    public int notesCount { get; set; }
    public int patientAccountId { get; set; }
    public int isRead { get; set; }
}

public class ItemConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private Type currentType;
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Item).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) || objectType == typeof(Notification);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);
        if (item["type"] != null)
        {
            // save the type for later.
            switch (item["type"].Value<int>())
            {
                case 1:
                    currentType = typeof(ItemA);
                    break;
                default:
                    currentType = typeof(ItemB);
                    break;
            }
            return item.ToObject<Notification>();
        }

        // use the last type you read to serialise.
        return item.ToObject(currentType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
        object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've this error: Type does not a defenition for 'IsAssignableFrom' and no extention method 'IsAssignableFrom' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found, in the line "return typeof(NotificationDetails).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) || objectType == typeof(Notification);"

Comment: instead of Item in your example, I created a class called NotificationDetails

Comment: Oh, it was because I was using it in a PCL, I solved it by replacing it with 
"return typeof(NotificationDetails).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) || objectType == typeof(Notification);"

Comment: Sorry, but I'm getting invalid cast exception when I am trying to cast it back

Comment: maybe start a discussion and post your code, I can try and take a look - I will need some more context to understand your cast problem. Alternatively post that code **as a new question** asking why the cast is failing. That way it's quite specific, and you should be able to get it solved quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use special JSON serializer settings, like

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };
```

Type name will be stored with actual "details" data, so you can deserialize it to valid class.

```
var instance = new Notification
        {
            details = new Details
            {
                Name = "Hello"
            }
        };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Produced json

```
{"$type":"Application.Notification, Application","details":{"$type":"Application.Details, Application","Name":"Hello"}}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var json = "{\r\n    \"timeAgo\": \"6 minutes ago\",\r\n    \"time\": \"07/11/2016 07:00 AM\",\r\n    \"alertId\": 145928,\r\n    \"details\": {\r\n\r\n\r\n    },\r\n    \"priority\": 10,\r\n    \"type\": 2,\r\n    \"isClosed\": 0,\r\n    \"notesCount\": 0,\r\n    \"patientAccountId\": 680,\r\n    \"isRead\": 0\r\n  }";
Notification data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Notification>(json);

var type=1;
if (type == 1)
   {
     string[] a = data.details as string[];
   }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: i will try next time